# $ phpbrew known PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function PhpBrew\json_decode() in phar:///usr/bin/phpbrew/src/PhpBrew/ReleaseList.php on line 49

Tags: php, json

I am getting this error after installing phpbrew. Even I am unable to switch to other php versions.

> $ phpbrew known PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function
>   PhpBrew\json_decode() in
>   phar:///usr/bin/phpbrew/src/PhpBrew/ReleaseList.php on line 49

Comment: You should probably report that to the maintainer of phpbrew.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least install a php with json extension. the json extension is required for fetching release info.